# Rendered model is broken

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

So I was finishing my model and I spotted this deformation.
I have bevel modifier applied, but turning it off doesn't fix it.
It also appears in rendered image
[image: The thing]

[image: Edit mode]

Comment: The problem is that likely you used booleans to cut the holes instead of modeling and you ended up with large ngons. Having large n-gons with non planar geometry will create creases  like the ones you are experiencing. Ngons are problematic and is a good practice trying to avoid them. [Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA) that shows many ways to do holes and keeping proper quad topology.

Comment: You could try setting the shading on you object to smooth, and then using an edge split modifier or using the Auto-Smooth normals option in the object data tab of the properties panel. This will shade areas that are mostly or completely flat as completely smooth, and should get rid of some of the visible edges.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to happen because you have an n-gonal surface (the side of the sword has more than 4 edges). Usually, when renderers encounter faces that have more than three or four edges, they get confused.

To fix this, try to select the face and 'triangulate' (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) it. This will split the faces into triangles, making the shape less ambiguous for the renderer.

If this doesn't work, you'll have to manually cut it up with the `knife` tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) until only quads and triangles remain. If you do this, try to make a uniform pattern (don't just cut randomly).

Comment: I tried the triangulate - didn't work, it was horrible. And than i did it with the knife tool, but i could still see the cuts, which i don't get why, because the circles were projected onto the big plane, so they all should be in a row - no edges